# Small input fields with responsive design in bootstrap(-vue)

Tags: html, css, bootstrap-4, bootstrap-vue

I try to create an input form with small fields and signs between them. 
[image]

Currently its done with a mix of classic HTML and Bootstrap-Vue.
As you can see in the screen shot. It works. 
But only on big screens. its not responsive. 
On mobile it looks like this:

[image]

The last field is overlaid by the button and the fields are to small to see the input.

If I only use bootstrap, the fields and spacings are way to big and I can't find a way to make them smaller.
And I think it would be a good idea to have the button in a new line on mobile. 
But how do I do it?

My code looks like this:

```html
<b-row>
  <b-col class="mt-3" cols="2">
    &nbsp;
  </b-col>
  <b-col class="mt-3">
    <b>Kundennummer:</b>
  </b-col>
</b-row>
<b-row>
  <b-col class="mt-3" cols="2">
    &nbsp;
  </b-col>
  <b-col class="mt-3 ml-0" cols="4">
    <table>
      <tr>
        <td class="m-0 p-0">
          <b-form-input id="case_no_0" ref="case_no_0" type="text" v-model="custNo[0]" :state="state[0]" maxlength="3" @focus="$event.target.select()" @input="formatter(0)"></b-form-input>
        </td>
        <td class="m-0 p-0">
          &nbsp;.&nbsp;
        </td>
        <td class="m-0 p-0">
          <b-form-input id="case_no_1" ref="case_no_1" type="text" v-model="custNo[1]" :state="state[1]" maxlength="3" @focus="$event.target.select()" @input="formatter(1)"></b-form-input>
        </td>
        <td class="m-0 p-0">
          &nbsp;.&nbsp;
        </td>
        <td class="m-0 p-0">
          <b-form-input id="case_no_2" ref="case_no_2" type="text" v-model="custNo[2]" :state="state[2]" maxlength="3" @focus="$event.target.select()" @input="formatter(2)"></b-form-input>
        </td>
        <td class="m-0 p-0">
          &nbsp;-&nbsp;
        </td>
        <td class="m-0 p-0">
          <b-form-input id="case_no_3" ref="case_no_3" type="text" v-model="custNo[3]" :state="state[3]" maxlength="4" @focus="$event.target.select()" @input="formatter(3)" @keyup.enter="validateAndSave()"></b-form-input>
        </td>
      </tr>
    </table>
  </b-col>
  <b-col class="mt-3">
    <b-button class="btn-evm-orange" @click="validateAndSave()">Senden</b-button>
  </b-col>
</b-row>
```

EDIT:

For people asking why I don't use just bootstrap and to the answer of Sirence

The fields get way to big, I want them to be nice and small, just big enough for 3 numbers.
Here screenshots of the comparison:

**PC-View**

[image]

**Mobile-View**

[image]

Comment: Is there a specific reason you need the table around the inputs? If you remove it you can work with the bootstrap responsive classes, which should be much easier.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you do not need the table, this is a way to achive a responsive form using the bootstrap responsive col classes as well as some utility classes:

```
  <b-row class="no-gutters">
  <b-col class="col-2 col-md-1">
    <b-form-input type="text" maxlength="3"></b-form-input>
  </b-col>
  <b-col class="col-auto align-self-end">&nbsp;.&nbsp;</b-col>
  <b-col class="col-2 col-md-1">
    <b-form-input type="text" maxlength="3"></b-form-input>
  </b-col>
  <b-col class="col-auto align-self-end">&nbsp;.&nbsp;</b-col>
  <b-col class="col-2 col-md-1">
    <b-form-input type="text" maxlength="3"></b-form-input>
  </b-col>
  <b-col class="col-auto align-self-center">&nbsp;-&nbsp;</b-col>
  <b-col class="col-2 col-md-1">
    <b-form-input type="text" maxlength="4"></b-form-input>
  </b-col>
  <b-col class="col-12 col-sm-auto pt-2 pl-sm-3 pt-sm-0">
    <b-button class="btn-evm-orange">Button</b-button>
  </b-col>
</b-row>
```

For a two row layout on xs devices:

```
<b-row class="no-gutters">
  <b-col class="col-3 col-sm-2 col-md-1">
    <b-form-input type="text" maxlength="3"></b-form-input>
  </b-col>
  <b-col class="col-auto align-self-end">&nbsp;.&nbsp;</b-col>
  <b-col class="col-3 col-sm-2 col-md-1">
    <b-form-input type="text" maxlength="3"></b-form-input>
  </b-col>
  <b-col class="col-auto align-self-end">&nbsp;.&nbsp;</b-col>
  <div class="w-100 pt-2 d-sm-none"></div><!-- this is a helper class -->
  <!-- see https://getbootstrap.com/docs/4.4/layout/grid/#column-breaks for info -->
  <b-col class="col-3 col-sm-2 col-md-1">
    <b-form-input type="text" maxlength="3"></b-form-input>
  </b-col>
  <b-col class="col-auto align-self-center">&nbsp;-&nbsp;</b-col>
  <b-col class="col-3 col-sm-2 col-md-1">
    <b-form-input type="text" maxlength="4"></b-form-input>
  </b-col>
  <b-col class="d-block d-sm-none col-auto align-self-center">
    &nbsp;&nbsp;&nbsp;
    <!-- this is just for symmetry -->
  </b-col>
  <b-col class="col-12 col-sm-auto pt-2 pl-sm-3 pt-sm-0">
    <b-button class="btn-evm-orange">Button</b-button>
  </b-col>
</b-row>
```

https://jsfiddle.net/Sirence/1rspht4u/9/

Inputs will be auto width from medium devices upwards.
They will be splitted into two rows for xs & sm devices.
The button is in a new row for xs & sm devices.
Replace md with sm everywhere if you want the break to be later.

Comment: thanks for you answer, but if I use your code, the input fields are way to big. See the  edit of my post. And thats exactly the problem I have and try to solve. I want the fields just beg enough for 3 numbers.

Comment: @Eardy Oh I missread that, I thought they were too small on small devices. If you need the smaller, just add a class like col-md-1 or 2 depending on what you need. I adjust the fiddle to reflect it: https://jsfiddle.net/Sirence/1rspht4u/3/ Are these more like the sizes you wanted?

Comment: @Eardy  Also in your screenshot, did you put the code outside of your container? You should place it inside.

Comment: yeah, that did the trick. thanks. and yes its inside the container. I just added it as an other row.